# Create chart with disjointed data in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 3 columns (month, count, amount) over many years.

```
2010-01, 10, 20
2010-02, 34, 34
...
2011-01, 30, 43
2011-02, 12, 23
...
2012-01, 45, 33
2012-02, 43, 22
```

I want to create charts for each month over the years.
So a chart for all January, February, etc.

I can do some scripting.  The google chart api (for web) offers newDataTable and setDataTable, which can work for disjointed data.  For the scripting in google sheets, it seems only range is available for charts.  Can I create virtual range (but that is just DataTable)?:-)  Any suggestion on how I can do this in Google Sheets?

** added 2020/05/12 **

I am not sure how to do query to get the appropriate dataset:-(

So I have decided to use script to create a range that is chart-friendly.

```
function setMonthlyStat(sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var value1, value2;
  var sourceX, sourceY;
  var row = 13; // number of years
  sourceX = 2; sourceY = 2; // starting x, y

  // continuous monthly value year by year (j*12 = offset by year)
  var stats = new Array(row);
  for (var i=0; i<=row-1; i++) { // vertical
    stats[i] = new Array(24);
    for (var j=0; j<=11; j++) { // horizontal
      // count
      value1 = ss.getRange(sourceX+j+i*12, sourceY).getValue();
      stats[i][j*2] = value1;
      // amount
      value2 =  ss.getRange(sourceX+j+i*12, sourceY+1).getValue();
      stats[i][j*2+1] = value2;
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("L2:AI14").setValues(stats); // the range is not the one in the screenshot
}
```

Note: ncount = #, namount = $

[image]

Comment: Make a real new range?

Comment: Yeah, the last resort is to create a new table programmatically with the range format the charts need,  I just want to find out if there is a way not to do this step and create the charts directly from the original data set:-)

Comment: I haven't done much charting, but is there some reason you want to use a script?  Won't a query or similar function pull the data for each month, and allow you to chart from the query results?

Comment: `=query()` will make grouping easier

Comment: I am not sure how to do query to get the appropriate dataset:-(

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.  If I understand correctly, your issue is getting the data into a format that you can make your chart from, not the actual charting.

This formula I think converts your original data into the format you need.  See the sample sheet below.

```
=query(DataA,"select D, sum(B), sum(C) " & L1 & " group by D pivot E label sum(B) 'Amt', sum(C) 'Cnt'",1)
```

A sample sheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12wboxcbSu-SBhbHzZWrhmVSLMt1QoyLYu8ErUuWlPJg/edit?usp=sharing

I've added some helper columns (D:F, hidden), but these could be removed and incorporated within the formula, if you prefer.  I'll see about adding the chart to the sheet later today.

Note that even though the query shows "SUM" for some columns, there is only one value per month per year, so the SUM is just for one value.  But it is needed if you need to be able to show all of the months for each year - ie. select "All" from the month picker in K1.  If you only ever need to see one month's data (eg. February) then the formula can be much simpler, as follows:

```
=QUERY(DataA,"SELECT D, B, C " & L1 & " ORDER BY D ",1)
```

Let me know if this is on the right track.

Comment: Not quite.  Right now I can do chart for all the months chronologically from the original data.  But I want to create charts for each months for all the years.  So I want a chart for all January, a chart of February, a chart of March, etc.  This way, I can compare the historic performance by month.

Comment: @Tom,  Can you please clarify why this isn't working?  If you look at Sheet1Bkup, I've selected "February", which filters all of the February data into I7:K.  The chart then uses that range, resulting in a chart for just February data.  Is this not what you are trying to achieve?  You can try the same, using different months, in Sheet1.

Comment: You are right.  It works.  You are just showing the month of September.

My original question is to find a way to create the charts directly.  It seems to be impossible.  So I use script to create data for the charts.  It seems query can do the same thing, but much easier.  

Great job!

It is definitely not easy to understand.  I need to take some time to study it:-)

Comment: I have a question.  If I change the value, how does your data get updated?  In your sample data, 2010/09 , count=1, amount=15, I change it to 2, and 3, your formula doesn't update the new data.   Why?

Comment: @Tom,  Sorry, I fixed the formula in I6.  It was using an old "named range", pointing to the backup sheet.  I corrected it to point to the named range for cells A6:F258.  Now if you change one of those values - in the right month - the chart beside it will change.  Let me know if you still have an issue.